# Cannot constrain UITableView to safe area

Tags: ios, autolayout

It does not appear possible to add constraints to a `UITableView`

I would like to add the "Align Top to: Safe Area" constraint to the table view because as you can see, cells do not appear to be within the safe area:

[image]

How do I constrain the table view to remain within the bounds of the safe area?

Comment: Check `automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets` and `tableView.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior` peoperties. The former should be set to `true` the latter to something other than `.never`.

Comment: And you need a version check `if #available(iOS 11.0, *) { tableView.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = .scrollableAxes }`

Answer (score 3):

Seems that you use UITableViewController. In this way you don't have a way to change default constrains of tableView. Only one thing you can do is to add a Navigation Controller. (Click on your UITableViewController than on the top of your display: Editor->Embed In-> Navigation Controller)

Another way is to add UITableView to UIViewController. In this case you can add any constrains you want.

Look thru the code below. This can help you figure out what should you do next.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController,UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    var data: [String] = ["Cell 1", "Cell 2", "Cell"]
    var colors: [UIColor] = [.red, .green, .blue]

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.reloadData()
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "id", for: indexPath)
        cell.textLabel?.text = data[indexPath.row]
        cell.contentView.backgroundColor = colors[indexPath.row]

        return cell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return data.count
    }

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

}
```

Finally you will get something like on the screenshot below.

P.S. Don't forget to add identifier to your prototype cell. In my example the identifier is "id"

[image: TableView]

Here is screenshot of all Xcode project.

[image: Xcode project]

Answer (score 2):

My solution was to change the `UITableViewController`, to a `UIViewController`, and add a UITableView to the view, then add the top, bottom, left and right constraints.

Note, that you will get a crash, until you change the class to inherit from `UIViewController`instead of `UITableViewController`

```
@interface MyViewController : UITableViewController
```

to

```
@interface MyViewController : UIViewController
```

you obviously also need to relink the UITableView, and connect the datasource and delegate, if you weren't doing that programatically